# Reporting with MySQL - Simplest Query taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a MySQL Table on an Amazon RDS Instance with 250 000 Rows. When I try to

```
SELECT * FROM  tableName
```

without any conditions (**just for testing**, the normal query specifies the columns I need, but I need most of them) , the query takes between 20 and 60 seconds to execute. This will be the base query for my report, and the report should run in under 60 seconds, so I think this will not work out (it times out the moment I add the joins). The report runs without any problems in our smaller test environments.

Could it be that the Query is taking so long because MySQL is trying to lock the table and waiting for all writes to finish? There might be quite a lot of writes on this table. I am doing the query on a MySQL slave, since I do not want to lockup the production system with my queries.

- I have no experience with how much rows are much for a relational DB. Are 250 000 Rows with ~30 columns (varchar, date and integer types) much?
- How can I speedup this query (hardware, software, query optimization ...)
- Can I tell MySQL that I do not care that the Data might be inconsistent (It is a snapshot from a Reporting Database)
- Is there a chance that this query will run under 60 seconds, or do I have to adjust my goals?

Comment: It might be helpful adding indexes to your table.

Comment: Which engine are you using? InnoDB, MyISAM? Neither of them should have any problems handling 250k rows. Check that the table is properly indexed. If you are using MyISAM, you could increase the key buffer size

Comment: I am using InnoDB. For a SELECT(*) what should I Index (this is basically what my application will be doing, I need to dump the table with some joins but they are all indexed).

Comment: If you're selecting all columns with no conditions, indexes won't help here.

Comment: Thought so, just asked to be sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that MySQL has to prepare your result set and transport it to your client. In your case, this could be 200MB of data it has to shuttle across the connection, so 20 seconds is not bad at all. Most libraries, by default, wait for the entire result being received before forwarding it to the application.

To speed it up, fetch *only* the columns you need, or do it in chunks with `LIMIT`. `SELECT *` is usually a sign that someone's being super lazy and not optimizing at all.

If your library supports streaming resultsets, use that, as then you can start getting data almost immediately. It'll allow you to iterate on rows as they come in without buffering the entire result.

Comment: I was able to talk with the client and to get criteria for the users he needs. So we are down to around 250 users, which are returned in far under a second. With all the Joins we need that goes up again to 60 seconds, but we are joining in tables with millions of records so that is O.K.
So the suggestion of not "FETCHING ALL THE ROWS!!!" was correct, and I will mark this Answer as accepted.

Comment: Additionaly a small comment to MYSQL views: If you have a VIEW of this table that does a "SELECT * FROM originalTable" and do a select query with a WHERE clause on the VIEW, the VIEW will first do the SELECT and than do the where on the Resultset it receives. And generating this resultset might take a long time even if the full result never has to go over the Network. I always thought that MySQL was so wise to apply the WHERE clauses I do on views to the original SELECT, but now I am wiser, and know that MySQL views are pretty dumb.

Comment: It's worth using the [MySQL Workbench tool](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to see if your server's configured correctly. The reason for slow performance might be exhausting certain memory pools, or using a temporary file on a slow hard disk. If you have the ability to add SSD to your server, that's the closest thing you'll get to a magic bullet. It can instantly increase speed 10-50x because random access times are near zero.

Comment: @tadman - as you have seen in the question we are on a Amazon RDS instance and have no control over the hardware. But we area already thinking about switching to own hardware.

Comment: @PaulWeber There are SSD-backed VPS providers like [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) and at some point Amazon may need to provide their own SSD instances. [Rackspace also has SSD options](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/block-storage/) for some of their configurations. While self-hosted hardware might be the best call for you in the long run, there are options for testing out or deploying in the interim.

Answer (score 2):

A table with 250,000 rows is not too big for MySQL at all.

However, waiting for those rows to be returned to the application does take time.  That is network time, and there are probably a lot of hops between you and Amazon.

Unless your report is really going to process all the data, check the performance of the database with a simpler query, such as:

```
select count(*) from table;
```

EDIT:

Your problem is unlikely to be due to the database.  It is probably due to network traffic.  As mentioned in another answer, streaming might solve the problem.  You might also be able to play with the data formats to get the total size down to something more reasonable.

A last-resort step would be to save the data in a text file, compress the file, move it over, and uncompress it.  Although this sounds like a lot of work, you might get 5x - 10x compression on the data, saving oodles of time on the transmission and still have a large improvement in performance with the rest of the processing.

Comment: Well, the report will have to process all the data, since the table contains exactly the data we need (minus some things that need to be joined). We just need an efficient way to fetch it somehow.

Comment: @PaulWeber . . . You should probably be doing the processing in the database and returning back a much smaller result set.  Returning back all the rows to do processing in the application rather defeats the purpose of using a database.

Comment: To explain: This database contains a report about all of our users, and the client wants an user report with the data of all of our users. So we gave him access to this database ...
But it's a good point, maybe I can filters out the most important users via query. The AC is still a report for all 250 000 rows though.

Comment: Just a small comment: I also tested this table behind a view that did a SELECT *, and there was a major misunderstanding for me. I always thought that MySQL will apply the WHERE clauses I use on the view to the original query. But no, it first does the original Query and fetches the Resultset after that.
I also tested limiting the Data returned from the view and the query never returned, so the problem seems to be that MySQL is not even able to prepare the Results, before it can filter them.
Well. The final solution was to filter the data to only relevant users in the VIEW query.

Comment: @PaulWeber . . . This may be the way the MySQL behaves.  Don't assume that all databases handle views in the same inefficient way.

Comment: Did not do that ... always mentioned MySQL, i know that Oracle and Postgres have materialized views ...

Answer (score 1):

I got updated specs from my client and was able to reduce the amount of users returned to 250, which goes (with a lot of JOINS) though in 60 seconds.

So maybe the answer is really: Try to not dump a whole table with a query, fetch only the exact data your need. The Client has SQL access, and he will have to update his queries, so only relevant users are returned.

Answer (score 0):

I should never really use * as a wildcard. Choose the fields that you actually want and then create an index of these fields combined.

Comment: Good suggestion, but in this special case I really need all the fields of this table, since it was generated specifically for this report. In the real query I even specify them all (to get aliases), but this is just a test query to get a performance estimate. Is your suggestion to create an index for all the fields in the table? I do not think this would be wise, do you?

Comment: @PaulWeber If that's the cause its most likely network latency. Get the database to do all the heavy work using a stored procedure where you just send the params and the database server returns the results.

Answer (score 0):

If you have thousands of rows, another option is implement pagination.
If result data directly using for report , no one can look more than 100 rows in single shot.